# Adding custom text to each Collection listed on homepage

Tags: text, collections, bigcartel

IN BIGCARTEL: Is there a way to add CUSTOM TEXT to each individual collection that is displayed on the home page? I want this text to only appear when the collections are listed on the home page and not anywhere else.

Adding the additional text to the collection name in the product section does not solve this.

Adding a custom HTML on the homepage appends the same custom text to all collections. Again not right.

Any advice on creating a text that appears only with a particular collection, and only on the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript, try this:

```
if(~window.location.pathname.indexOf('index'){
    // your code
}
```

The code above will run it only on index.html, which is your homepage.